# How do we prove that $\lim_{x\to\pi/4}\cos(2x)/(1-\sqrt{2}\sin(x)) = 2$ without L'Hôpital?

Tags: calculus

How can I prove the following limit equals two without LHopital?

Through L'Hôpital, I reached this conclusion:

$$\lim _{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\cos 2 x}{1-\sqrt{2} \sin x}=2$$

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) = \cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x) = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(x) = (1 - \sqrt{2}\sin(x))(1+\sqrt{2}\sin(x)) 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad to be of help.